# App rejected by Google for violating the Permissions policy

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, android-permissions

When I uploaded a new .apk to the Google Play store, its uploaded but even after some time, it rejected my submission saying, "Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Permissions policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through the policy and make sure your app is in compliance".
After that, I have updated Apk file with the new version and attached with a video link and its shows your app is not meet with call and SMS permission. Please Help me out this issue how to live my app again. Mainly I have already filled up the google permission form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOHEq.png)

Comment: filling and submitting permission form won't guarantee that your app will be allowed.

Comment: @karanMer Its granted for my app google have sent a mail regarding it

Comment: then follow them up with the mail that you have received.

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal Can you please tell me what was the use case of your app for which you got approval? My app is struck with the same and waiting for them to review my use case since last days :(

Comment: @Sandip I have just used for the permission for  making a call.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered this problem, when uploaded a new .apk to the Google Play store. Our new apk is meet new Google Permissions Policy about SMS and CALL. We remove these permissions from app completely and provide a video link, but our app update was rejected according to these permissions.

Google support team sent an email to solve this issue as follow;

To solve this issue, you will have to discard the draft artifacts containing sensitive permissions and create a new release without those permissions.

Here is how to check within the Play Console:

1. Go to Release Management > Artifact Library
2. Expand Active APKs and Draft APKs
3. Expand Required Permissions for each APK

You may also want to review the [Permissions](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/) policy and review the [Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303) help article, which describes intended uses, exceptions, invalid uses, and alternative implementation options for additional guidance.